# Can't create log file through adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

My working directory is `/data/local/tmp`.

I create and push a shell script file here named `get_meminfo.sh`.

The core function of it is record the RSS usage and save as a log file, like this: `rss_res >> rss.log`

But now I find a problem: I can run the script file when I enter the android shell, like ./get_meminfo.sh, and I can see the log file created in the path.

However when I try to run it from adb, like: `adb shell /data/local/tmp/get_meminfo.sh`， it will get an error: can't create file, read-only file system!

Comment: can you paste output of this command "adb shell id" 
and after you enter adb shell then execute "id"

output on my machine is same for both commands 
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)

ls -la /data/local/                                                                                                                                 
drwxr-x--x  3 root   root   4096 2018-11-22 12:27 .
drwxrwx--x 38 system system 4096 2018-11-23 12:57 ..
drwxrwx--x  2 shell  shell  4096 2018-11-23 16:14 tmp

shell:shell has write permission in /data/local/tmp/ so ideally you should be able to execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not quite understand the concept of the [*current working dirtectory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

The `rss_res >> rss.log` command creates `rss.log` in the current working dirtectory. Which in case of the following command sequence is `/data/local/tmp`:

```
adb shell
cd /data/local/tmp
./get_meminfo.sh
```

So `rss.log` gets created in `/data/local/tmp` which is world writable.

But in case of `adb shell /data/local/tmp/get_meminfo.sh` the *cwd* is the `/` *root* folder. Which is not writable and the command fails.

The easiest way to mitigate that is to use the absolute path for your log file inside of your script like this `rss_res >> /data/local/tmp/rss.log`